# ¿Se puede ver todas las instancias de los servidores de Azure en un solo monitor?

Tags: azure

Se puede ver todas las instancias de los servidores de Azure para tener una sola visualización en un monitor.

Comment: entiendo te refieres al portal de Azure, pero que serian las instancias? te refieres a los web site, VM o que serian estas instancias?

Answer (score 0):

Si entendi bien lo que estas planteando creo que deberias analizar el `Azure Resource Manager`

[Información general del Administrador de recursos de Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/)

este te permitira organizar los elementos de Azure agrupandolos en una sola vista para facilitar la administracion